# Can you hop on 1 leg twice when you have gathered the ball in basketball?

Tags: rules, basketball

If you have the ball gathered on 1 foot, I know you can jump and land on both feet at the same time and that it is a valid play (Jump Stop).

What happens if you gather the ball on 1 foot, then jump off that foot and then land on it again.
Is that a travel?

Answer (score 3):

At least in the NBA, this is a travel, and is a fairly new rule. You cannot gather, jump off of one foot, and then land on that same foot. I'm sure if other leagues haven't adopted this rule it's only a matter of time.

Comment: Right, but isnt that just strange? Like you can gather on 1 foot and jump then land on BOTH feet. But you are not allowed to land on ONLY that same foot (which would be less useful, and harder) ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that they aren't landing on ONLY one foot. They are gathering the ball as they jump off of one foot, landing on that same foot to establish it as the pivot, and then placing their non pivot foot down, which they then jump off of to attack the rim. typically this would be allowed, as the play doesn't become a travel unless the pivot foot returns to the floor before the ball is released for a shot or a pass. The NBA has ruled that going forward it IS a travel to gather, hop off of one foot and then land on that same foot, as it allows the ball handler too much of an advantage in terms of changing direction with the ball.

This video probably explains it better than I ever could, and has some real time examples that illustrate what it looks like and why it isn't being allowed:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmW76a-vbA0

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE, and thanks for your contributions thus far. If this was meant to be a response to [this comment](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/can-you-hop-on-1-leg-twice-when-you-have-gathered-the-ball-in-basketball#comment14875_7044), please do so in [a comment](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), not another answer. If this was meant to add on to your existing answer, please [edit](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/editing) it.

Comment: err..in that video it is clearly a travel regardless of that "new rule" since what happens is, as you were saying, gathering off that 1 foot then jumping then landing on that same foot, however their OTHER foot then follows after. Which is 3 steps with the ball gathered, so a travel anyway. My question is what happens if they then DO NOT land that other foot, and just use that same foot to hop on twice?

Answer (score 1):

In FIBA it's also a travel, according to [FIBA Official Basketball Rules 2020](https://www.fiba.basketball/documents/official-basketball-rules-yellow/2020.pdf) Rule 25.2.1:

> A player may not touch the floor consecutively with the same foot or both feet after ending his dribble or gaining control of the ball.

Answer (score -1):

No it’s a travel at every level. You can’t leave the floor with the ball, so step, and then land that foot first.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Sports SE. Please add a source to your answer if possible